# Spotify Metadata API + libspotify

Tags: javascript, php, spotify, libspotify, spotify-app

I'm studying the **Spotify Metadata API** and currently, the only data that are available are its music catalogue.

I would like to be able to pull a Spotify user's playlists/most frequent/most recent played tracks or artists. And by looking at the **Spotify Apps API**, basic user details can be retrieved. I don't know *Objective C* (Libspotify SDK).

Here are my questions:

- Is it possible to use the Request URL for Spotify Apps with the web app I'll be creating? Or use both the **Metadata API** and the **Libspotify SDK**?
- I've found this github repo, [Spotify iQuiz](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-iquiz), he was able to pull the playlists of a Spotify user and generate them as questions. Can you please help me breakdown his *spotify-api-wrapper.js* as well as the *spotify-playlist-importer.js*? I went through the code and he was using a different requestURL.
- If item 1 is feasible, is it possible to pull the most frequent/recent tracks a user listens to?
- *this is me extensively thinking or complicating*: Is Echo Nest a good tool to use too? Or will this complicate things further?

I'm really sorry for this lengthy post, I'm just facing a roadblock right now. And I'm trying to decide whether I should continue or shelve my idea for now. Thank you for your responses!

[*Doc links : pastebin*](http://pastebin.com/HiRHewAw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Spotify Apps API** is only available inside the Spotify client - if you're writing an app that's on the greater web or is otherwise standalone, it's not the API for you.

iQuiz uses the new beta Web API, which isn't publicly documented yet.

Listening history is not available through any Spotify API. If the user scrobbles to Last.fm, you can use their APIs instead.

Your question doesn't mention libspotify at all other than in the title and tags, so I don't know what you want that for.

Comment: @iKendacc Hey man! Thanks for your quick reply. Hmm. I also found this [Github Repo](https://github.com/liesen/spotify-api-server).

Part of their readme requires libspotify.

Are the artist recommendations available in the 'Discover' tab available in the API?

Comment: @iKendacc if listening history isn't available in any Spotify API, is it possible to use a _counter_ that will be saved in my database after every played track?

Comment: @iKendacc is there a way to know if a Spotify user is scrobbling to last.fm? Thanks!